# Derivation of the Wallis' product using trigonometry

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, pi

I wanted to know if the method I used is valid and not just pure luck:

Consider the function:
$$\dfrac{\cos(\frac{\pi x}{2})}{(x^2-1)}$$
The roots of the equation are$\quad\pm3,5,7,9,\cdots$

So the function can be represented as $$(1+\frac{x}{-3})(1+\frac{x}{3})(1+\frac{x}{-5})(1+\frac{x}{5})\cdots=(1-\frac{x^2}{3^2})(1-\frac{x^2}{5^2})(1-\frac{x^2}{7^2})\cdots$$

So $$\dfrac{\cos(\frac{\pi x}{2})}{(x^2-1)}=(1-\frac{x^2}{3^2})(1-\frac{x^2}{5^2})(1-\frac{x^2}{7^2})\cdots$$

Substitute $x=1$, the LHS becomes, by L'Hopital's rule, $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$

So $$\dfrac{\pi}{4}=(1-\frac{1}{3^2})(1-\frac{1}{5^2})(1-\frac{1}{7^2})\cdots=\frac{8}{9}\frac{24}{25}\frac{48}{49}$$

This can be rewritten as:$\dfrac{2\cdot4}{3\cdot3}\dfrac{4\cdot6}{5\cdot5}\dfrac{6\cdot8}{7\cdot7}\cdots$

So $$\dfrac{\pi}{2\cdot2}=\dfrac{2\cdot4}{3\cdot3}\dfrac{4\cdot6}{5\cdot5}\dfrac{6\cdot8}{7\cdot7}\cdots$$

So $$\dfrac{\pi}{2}=\dfrac{2\cdot2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot6\cdot8\cdot8\cdots}{1\cdot3\cdot3\cdot5\cdot5\cdot7\cdot7\cdots}$$

Comment: Oh also the coefficient of $x^2$ in the LHS matches that in the RHS $\frac{\pi^2}{8}-1$

Comment: You can also derive it using the infinite product for $\sin x$.

Comment: Ohh can I extend this to any trigonometric function? For instance can something like $\cos(x^2)$ also be represented in this format? What are the rules of such a transformation?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem This might also be interesting for you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem

Comment: Niice thanks a lot!!